# NAudio capture to a wav file

Tags: c#, naudio

I am receiving packets from DIS from network and want to convert these into wav file. I add buffer to my provider as below.

```
   WaveFileWriter writer;

   public Player()
   {
      writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"c:\_temp\file.wav", waveProvider.WaveFormat);
   }

    public void AddSamples(byte[] leftDataBuffer)
    {
        waveProvider.AddSamples(leftDataBuffer, 0, leftDataBuffer.Length);
        writer.Write(leftDataBuffer, 0, leftDataBuffer.Length);
    }
```

How can I keep adding the buffer to the same file in this function itself? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if are you trying to play the audio, or just save it to WAV. If just creating a WAV, use `WaveFileWriter` instead of `BufferedWaveProvider` and call `Write` passing in the received audio.

But you can use both if you want, writing received data to both a `WaveFileWriter` and putting it into a `BufferedWaveProvider` for live playback.

Comment: I want to use BufferedWaveProvider because I want to play it live but at the same time want to create a wav file as well.

Comment: OK, so have a WaveFileWriter and call Write on it with the contents of leftDatabuffer

Comment: I tried that. It records in a wav file but on hearing the wav file, it very slow/ delayed as though each word is very stretched. I have updated my code

Comment: sounds like you have the wrong WaveFormat. Stereo instead of mono perhaps?

Comment: I am using the same waveformat as of the waveProvider (can be seen in the code). Also the DirectSoundOut (during play) should give me the same result?